# Bootstrap modal dialog is not working when using SbAdmin template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

What is wrong with my code below?

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>EcoSystem - SBM ITB Jakarta</title>

<!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Page-Level Plugin CSS - Dashboard -->
<link href="../css/plugins/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/plugins/timeline/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- SB Admin CSS - Include with every page -->
<link href="../css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
<script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

<!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts - Dashboard -->
<script src="../js/plugins/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/plugins/morris/morris.js"></script>

<!-- SB Admin Scripts - Include with every page -->
<script src="../js/sb-admin.js"></script>

<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Dashboard - Use for reference -->
<script src="../js/demo/dashboard-demo.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
```

My bootstrap modal dialog is not working when I use SbAdmin template. But, when I use general template from bootstrap, my modal dialog is working properly.

Comment: Are you using jquery & bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes, I'm using them both.

Comment: (a) Try [Bootlinting](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your page (b) Show us the `<body>` code!

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha.. how stupid I am...

Just remove this code :

```
<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Dashboard - Use for reference -->
<script src="../js/demo/dashboard-demo.js"></script>
```